# Querying Map.Values() by using IPredicate in Hazelcast in .net client

Tags: .net, hazelcast

I have been told by a member of Hazelcast support team that I need to use IPortable implementation in order to use IPredicate queries in Map.Values().

I can sucessfully map values into the map and also get all of them with `Map.Values()`.  Please see below sample code.

However, when I try to query Map.Values() with SqlPredicate I get an error saying:

"An unhandled exception of type 'Hazelcast.Core.QueryException occured in Hazelcast.Net.dll'. Additional information: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Field count[2] in stream does not match ClassDefinition{factoryId=1, classId=1, version=0, fieldDefinitions=[FieldDefinitionImpl{index=0, fieldName='Name', type=UTF,..."

My config:

```
        var clientConfig = new ClientConfig();
        clientConfig.GetNetworkConfig().AddAddress(hazelCastIpAddress);
        clientConfig.SetGroupConfig(new GroupConfig(groupId, password));
        clientConfig.GetSerializationConfig().AddPortableFactory(MyDataSerializableFactory.FactoryId, new MyDataSerializableFactory());
```

My Hazelcast repository:

```
    private IHazelcastInstance _hazelcastClient;
    public IMap<object, TEntity> Map { get; }

    public HazelCastRepository(IHazelcastInstance hazelcastClient)
    {
        _hazelcastClient = hazelcastClient;
        Map = hazelcastClient.GetMap<object, TEntity>(typeof(TEntity).Name);
    }

    public void Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        Map.Set(entity.MapKey, entity); // map sets correctly with MapKey
    }

    public ICollection<TEntity> Get(string where)
    {
        var x = Map.Values(); // get all values and it works properly

        var y = new EqualPredicate("Id", 6);

        return Map.Values(y); // code breaks here with an error java.lang.IllegalStateException bla bla...
    }
```

IPortableFactory implementation:

```
public class MyDataSerializableFactory : IPortableFactory
{

    public const int FactoryId = 1;

    public IPortable Create(int classId)
    {
        var type = HazelcastContext.Models[classId];

        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        return (IPortable)instance;
    }
}

public class HazelcastContext
{

    public static Dictionary<int, Type> Models = new Dictionary<int, Type>() {
        { 1, typeof(MyTestModel)},
        { 2, typeof(MySecondTestModel) }

    };

}
```

My object class:

```
public class MyTestModel: IPortable
{


    public string Name { get; set; }
    public long Id { get; set; }

    public Guid MapKey
    {
        get; set;
    } = Guid.NewGuid();

    public int GetClassId()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public int GetFactoryId()
    {
        return 1;
    }

    public void ReadPortable(IPortableReader reader)
    {
        Name = reader.ReadUTF("Name");
        Id = reader.ReadLong("Id");
    }

    public void WritePortable(IPortableWriter writer)
    {
        writer.WriteUTF("Name", Name);
        writer.WriteLong("Id", Id);

    }
}
```

Comment: Can your your SqlPredicate, too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those who come error this error, I have a solution for this problem.

I contacted hazelcast's support team via their gitter.im room and had some advice but it didn't help me. There is a paragraph in [Mastering Hazelcast IMDB](https://hazelcast.org/mastering-hazelcast/)  saying:

> The *getFactoryId* should return a unique positive number, and the *getId* should return a unique positive number within its corresponding `PersonDataSerializableFactory`. Thus, `IdentifiedDataSerializable` implementations can return the same ID as long as the *getFactoryId* is different.

So, the propblem was the *factoryId*. If you encounter an error like this, clear your data on hazelcast and chang the *factoryId* you use. Then hazelcast will do the trick.

I believe it is because I had done many tests on hazelcast, as being very "fragile", somehow she got confused.